# What is the Taylor series for $\ln(1-x^2)$ around x=0 point?

Tags: taylor-expansion

As you can see from the title I need Taylor series for $$\ln(1-x^2)$$.
I am not sure which Taylor series to use:
$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$$ or
$$\ln(x)=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$$
Also I am not sure if this has any effect on question or answer but I am also given that I should setup my series around x=0 point.
I would really appreciate any help as it is my exam few days later.

Comment: Hint: $1 - x^2 = (1 - x)(1 + x)$ and $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$.

Comment: At least one of your proposals is wrong. Otherwise, $\log(x(1-x))=0$ would hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$$
let $x\rightarrow x^2$
$$\ln(1-x^2)=-\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understood the fundementals but I still wasn't sure and I am certain that this question will be on my semester exams so I wanted to ask people with more knowledge to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The first series converges for $|x|<1$ so changing $x$ to $x^{2}$ in it gives you the answer: $$\ln (1-x^{2})=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {x^{2n}} n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the derivatives of $\log(1+x)$, evaluated at $x=0$.

$$\log(1+x)\to0$$

$$(\log(1+x))'=(1+x)^{-1}\to1$$
$$\left((1+x)^{-1}\right)'=-(1+x)^{-2}\to-1$$
$$\left(-(1+x)^{-2}\right)'=2(1+x)^{-3}\to2$$
$$\cdots$$
$$(-1)^nn!(1+x)^{-n-1}\to(-1)^nn!$$

From this we get the Taylor development

$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots$$

Now we can either directly substitute $x$ for $-x^2$,

$$\log(1-x^2)=-x^2-\frac{x^4}2-\frac{x^6}3-\frac{x^8}4-\cdots$$

or add and simplify

$$\log(1+x)+\log(1-x)=x-x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots
\\=-x^2-\frac{x^4}2-\cdots$$